# How can texture images be loaded from local host, without web server and without disable browser security, with ThreeJS?

Tags: jquery, three.js, textures, cross-origin-read-blocking

I'm using the ThreeJS framework in an HTML page loaded from the desktop to load a texture:

```
var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('texture/plastic/plastic_2.jpg');
```

Of course, due to security feature the browsers can't allow load resources from local filesystem and return error.

I can't put this page in web server, I can't disable browser security and I can't host images online: everything must run from the desktop.

Is there another way to load a texture object?

Comment: Host the image online, for example http://imgur.com, and link to it there

Comment: you are right, but I've forgotten to add this restriction: I can't host image online, everything must run on the host from the desktop.

Comment: Your last resort then would be to attempt to base64 encode the image and load that in to ThreeJS - assuming it's even possible. If not, then there's nothing else you can do.

Comment: I'll try, thank you

Comment: Upon a cursory Google it appears it is possible to load the image from a base64 string: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755406/load-textures-from-base64-in-three-js

Comment: Use Firefox, so far it allows to load files from local drives.

Comment: Try installing xampp and creating a local server (Can be done within minutes)

Comment: Have you tried following the instructions in the [How to run things locally](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/How-to-run-things-locally) section of the docs?

Comment: @Marquizzo sure! The first way says "Change security for local files in a browser", I can't in my case as I describe in my question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching and trying, the best way to solve my problem as I described above,*I can't put this page in web server, I can't disable browser security and I can't host images online: everything must run from the desktop*, is: `use Firefox`!

With it, thanks to @prisoner849, **Firefox allows to load files from local drive and without disable security system**.

I hope this question helps everybody **to save time**.